# Open session is called when connection pool is out of connections in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, session

I'm using hibernate 5.2.10 with MySQL database. Also, I'm using C3PO to handle my connection pool. My C3PO configuration is as the following:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
```

However inside my application I have almost a 100 threads dealing with this connection pool asking for connections by calling:

```
sessionFactory.openSession();
```

When they are done with the session they use the following to close it:

```
session.close();
```

The application is running fine so far, but I feel that something is missing. As far as I understood that sessions number is bounded to connections number. So, if it happens that all the 100 threads called `openSession` simultaneously, what is going to happen?

- Will this call block for 50 threads (Since the maximum size of my connection pool is 50), and it can continue one by one once the first 50 threads are finished?
- Will 50 threads manage to get session while the other 50 threads throw exceptions?
- Is sessions number not related to the number of connections in connection pool, and I can open as many sessions as I want?

I'm fine with the first and third options, but it's the second option that I'm afraid of.

Comment: Why don't you just test it? But, unless c3p0 is really weirdly implemented, option 1 is the one.

Comment: Actually I did just test it, and option 1 was not the one. It seems like option 3 is the one, but I have no idea why.